# How to get a column value using MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to get a value from column "odznak" in "users" tab for user "user01" and store it in variable $odznak (for searching in another tab.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT odznak FROM users WHERE username = 'user01'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt;
$odznak;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the data (say into an associative array)

On the other hand, as a good practice, please use parameterized prepared statement in your select query

So, change to:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT odznak FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", 'user01');
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$odznak=$row["odznak"];
```

Now, $odznak is the retrieved data

Comment: and for example, if I want to get $odznak as a Integer?

Comment: @MartinTrnka it is already integer (if this field is int in the database)